# Using Test displayname with DynamicDataDisplayName in MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest, displayname-attribute

[TestMethod("My Test Name")] can be use to change the name of a test in MSTest.
DynamicData attribute can be used to run the test on a collection of object where you can customize the datadisplayname for each run.

Unfortunately, when you try to use both for the same test like below, the test is not affected by the display name set.
Any idea if it's possible to get the two attributes working at the same time.

```
[TestMethod("My Test")]
[DynamicData(nameof(MyTestObject), DynamicDataSourceType.Property, DynamicDataDisplayName = nameof(GetTestDisplayName))]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `[TestMethod]` with no name?

Comment: You might need `[DataTestMethod]` instead of `[TestMethod]` as well.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I use it but it then does not work with Dynamic object

Comment: @GregBurghardt in which UT framework can you use DataTestMethod

Comment: The MS Test framework. Same one you are using.